# Undefined control sequence \maketitle apa6 journal

Tags: errors, undefined

I am making a journal with `apa6` but when I make all the preamble, and put the make a `\title` command the editor says

> undefined control sequence line 11

(which is `\maketitle`). My code:

```
\documentclass[jou]{apa6}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[afilliation]
\title{La tutela como mecanismo}
\twoauthors{Mariana)}{Jose}
\leftheader{Jaramillo, Aristizabal}

\abstract{aqui va el abstract}
\keywords{palabras clave}
\begin{document}
\maketitle 
yo llevare 



\end{document}
```

Comment: Where can we get the `afilliation` package (btw the synatx is wrong, it should be `\usepackage{...}`)

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

- the affiliations for the authors are missing, add `\twoaffiliations{Affil. of 1st Author(s)}{Affil. 2nd Author(s)}`
- the syntax `\usepackage[afilliation]` is wrong, there should be `{}` around the package name. Anyway this package seems not to be included in standard tex installations and not available from ctan, so I cannot say if it would work if the syntax error would be fixed...

---

```
\documentclass[jou]{apa6}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
%\usepackage{afilliation}
\title{La tutela como mecanismo}
\twoauthors{Mariana}{Jose}
\twoaffiliations{Affil. of 1st Author(s)}{Affil. 2nd Author(s)}
\leftheader{Jaramillo, Aristizabal}

\abstract{aqui va el abstract}
\keywords{palabras clave}
\begin{document}
\maketitle 
yo llevare 

\end{document}
```